# How to say "I found my glasses"

Tags: verbs

I know it's a simple question but I want to be sure if the answer so I don't get confused. I know to search is 探す but what about "I found (something)"? Because 探した　doesn't seem correct and seems like it would mean "I searched".

> メガネを見つかった？Or メガネを見つかっていた？

Comment: First option with か→け.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The former option is close, but you should use transitive 見つける instead of 見つかる.

> メガネを見つけた - (I) found my glasses

The reason you should use 見つける instead of 見つかる is because the former is transitive (takes a direct object, with を) and the latter is intransitive (is done on its own). In other words, 見つける is the process of *someone* finding *something*, whereas 見つかる is *something being found*.

So using 見つかる is not wrong, but you'll have to change up the sentence a bit, since using を with it is ungrammatical.

> メガネは見つかった - My glasses are found

見つかる emphasizes that it was found, maybe by accident; 見つける emphasizes that *someone* found it, probably by looking for it.

Whenever you finally find something you've been looking for, you exclaim 「見つかった！」 ("Found it!") rather than 「見つけた！」.

Comment: I think you could exclaim 「あった！」

Comment: "I think you could exclaim 「あった！」" --> Totally agreed, we'd definitely say 「あった！」. You might exclaim 見つかった！ when you are found by someone, like when you're playing hide and seek, hiding from someone/stalker/zombie etc, and 見つけた！ when you have found someone when playing hide and seek or you're the stalker, like "Oh there you are! I found you!"

Answer (score 0):

I would say "メガネは、みつかりました。".    ..

Comment: It's good to know what you would say. However to make it an answer on SE you should add a little background information or references.

Answer (score 0):

I found my glasses(Feminine and adults)　－　私のメガネを見つけた。

I found my glasses(Boy)　－　僕はメガネを見つけた。

Comment: Why do females and adults use の while boys use は?